# Selenium Server with MagickImage.NET

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, imagemagick, selenium-webdriver

Not sure if this is a Selenium Server issue, MagickImage.NET issue or something else altogether.

I have a unit test that compares a selenium screenshot with an approved screenshot using MagickImage.net (a wrapper for Image Magick). For testing purposes I have a unit test that does this comparison with just MagickImage.net independant of Selenium server. The standalone test works but when I run the Selenium test I get the below error as though the instance of the test running through Selenium doesn't know what Magick.NET is.

[image]

I have tried various versions of MagickImage (86, 64, .net 2.0 and 4.0) with no luck. I have also tried installing the dll into the GAC and have used dll references and through nuget and I still have not luck.

any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the issue. My Test project was set to AnyCPU and I set it to x86 and it started to work. So it has nothing to do with Selenium or MagickImage, it is just a problem with a solution that is all 64 but a test project that is x86.

Comment: Magick.NET requires that you specify the architecture. Instead of AnyCPU you should use x86 or x64.